# How can I data-bind a dynamically-created control?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dynamic

In the past, I've created data bindings like so:

```
textBoxPlatypusName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", PlatypusInfo, "PlatypusName"));
```

...but with dynamically-created controls, this is not possible (the compiler wouldn't be able to recognize "textBoxPlatypusName" at compile-time).

Trying this:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBoxPlatypusName", true).First();
(TextBox)tb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", PlatypusInfo, "PlatypusName"));
```

...gives me, "*Cannot convert type 'void' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'*" and "*Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*"

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the type casting. It is not required, since `tb` is already strongly typed as `TextBox`. The casting is wrong here anyway.

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBoxPlatypusName", true).First();
tb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", PlatypusInfo, "PlatypusName"));
```

If `tb` was typed as `object` or `Control`, for instance, and you needed to cast it to `TextBox`, you would need a second set of parentheses

```
((TextBox)control).SomePropertyOfTextBox = x;
```

Otherwise the casting is applied to the entire expression. In your case, C# wants to apply the casting to the result of the `Add` method, which is `void` and cannot be casted.